# Mirror text from from form input into div in multiple places

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to get text entered into a text input to show in a div. That div would appear in multiple place within in a page. I've been able to figure out how to have the text appear in the div but it only will appear in the first instance of the div.

Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
     var input = $('#char2name'),
    preview = $('#previewchar2name');

input.keyup(function(e) {
    preview.text(input.val());
});
});
```

And My form input is as follows:

```
<label>Character 2's Name</label><input type="text" name="char2name" id="char2name" />
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

basically youre using an id where you should be using a class

if youre trying to change the text of multiple preview elements, change  all of them to something like this:

```
<div class="previewchar2name"></div>
```

and then change your script to something like this in the applicable areas:

```
preview = $('.previewchar2name');

input.keyup(function(e) {
    preview.each(function(){$(this).text(input.val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to get this to work for multiple input fields but it doesn't work for the second, third, etc. fields. I've setup a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmmoze/3dMqU/5/

Comment: @Johny53228  see this jsfiddle.  you just spelled the second var wrong.  http://jsfiddle.net/3dMqU/6/